# ValidateAsync Identity Server 4 passing dbConnection

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have already set up a `dbConnection` singleton in my `Startup.cs`

```
var dbConection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase"));
services.AddSingleton(dbConection);
```

Now I want to get the `dbConnection` in my `ValidateAsync` method, but I can not pass it:

```
public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context, SqlConnection dbConnection)
```

because it is not a proper interface for the `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`

How can I receive or read the `dbConnection` inside `ValidateAsync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass the `SqlConnection` in the constructor:

```
public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(SqlConnection dbConnection)
{
    _dbConnection = dbConnection;
}
```

Then we can access to `_dbConnection` inside `ValidateAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

If we pass the SqlConnection then where is the context with its data?